# How to check attribute value is equal to oue value and get the value of another attribute in that element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the particular data-val value. I receive the index value. I need to get data-val's value that which div's data-ind attibute have that index value.

```
<div data-ind="1" data-val="A"></div>
<div data-ind="2" data-val="B"></div>
<div data-ind="3" data-val="C"></div>
<div data-ind="4" data-val="D"></div>
<div data-ind="5" data-val="E"></div>
```

Comment: `$('div[data-ind=1]').attr('data-val')` something like to for `data-ind = 1`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var dataind = 1;
console.log($('div[data-ind=' + dataind + ']').attr('data-val'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-ind="1" data-val="A"></div>
<div data-ind="2" data-val="B"></div>
<div data-ind="3" data-val="C"></div>
<div data-ind="4" data-val="D"></div>
<div data-ind="5" data-val="E"></div>
```

use [attr selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

> Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `data-*` selector and `.attr()` to get `data-val` as shown :-

```
var ind = "1";
$("div[data-ind = '" + ind + "']").attr('data-val');
```

OR use `.data()` as shown :-

```
var ind = "1";
$("div[data-ind = '" + ind + "']").data('val');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.each($("div[data-ind]"),function(k,v){
   var val = $(v).attr("data-val");
   alert("data-ind="+(k+1)+": "+val);
});

});
```

It will pop up alert as

```
data-ind=1: A
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sum1/bcazbLee/3/

Answer (score 0):

**Use This:**

```
$.each($("div[data-ind]"),function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('data-val'));
   alert($(this).attr('data-val'));
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var check = '5';
var value = $('div[data-ind= '+check+']').attr('data-val');

alert(value);

});
```